# how to plugin custom RazorViewEngine in ASP.NET 5 beta6

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

In previous beta4 and beta5 I was able to plugin a custom RazorViewEngine with code like this:

```
services.AddMvc().Configure<MvcOptions>(options =>
{
    options.ViewEngines.Clear();
    options.ViewEngines.Add(typeof(MyViewEngine));
});
```

but after upgrading to beta6 now it says there is no ViewEngines on MvcOptions

I tried adding it by DI instead like this:

```
services.TryAdd(ServiceDescriptor.Transient<IRazorViewEngine, MyViewEngine>());
```

but no luck. Does anyone know what the new way to accomplish this would be?

Answer (score 5):

found it from the latest announcements:

```
services.AddMvc().ConfigureMvcViews(options =>
{
    options.ViewEngines.Clear();
    options.ViewEngines.Add(typeof(MyViewEngine));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This has now changed to:

```
services.AddSingleton<IMyViewEngine, MyViewEngine>();
```

Comment: yes this question was specific to beta6, it was changed in beta7 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32416007/how-to-plugin-custom-viewengine-in-mvc-6-beta7/32416243#32416243