# how to plugin custom viewengine in MVC 6 beta7?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

in beta6 we were able to plugin a custom viewengine like this:

```
services.AddMvc()
.AddViewOptions(options =>
 {
     options.ViewEngines.Clear();
     options.ViewEngines.Add(typeof(MyCustomViewEngine));

 });
```

this no longer works in beta7 and options.ViewEngines seems to have changed to an

```
IList<IViewEngine>
```

I don't understand how to plug one in without having to new it up and provide its dependencies

```
options.ViewEngines.Add(new it up here?);
```

How can I plug in my own custom viewengine in beta7?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I figured it out, before calling

```
services.AddMvc()
```

I need to add my viewengine to DI

```
services.TryAddSingleton<IRazorViewEngine, MyCustomViewEngine>();
```